# Propiedad no definida

Tags: php, mvc

estoy intentando comunicar mi modelo con mi controlador en mvc, el problema que en el controlador si me esta cargando la vista pero no me carga el modelo y no se por que siempre da este error:
Aviso : Propiedad no definida: Clientes :: $ model
me gustaría saber como solucionarlo, se supone que esta el modelo iniciado y todo pero no se por que no funciona

**Controllers/Clientes.php**

```
class Clientes extends Controllers
{

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function home()
{
    // $data['page_id'] = 1;
    $data['tag_page'] = "GymArt";
    $data['page_title'] = "Clientes";
    $data['page_content'] = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et, quis. Perspiciatis repellat perferendis accusamus, ea natus id omnis, ratione alias quo dolore tempore dicta cum aliquid corrupti enim deserunt voluptas.";
    // $data["clientes"] =$this->verUsuarios();

    $this->views->getView($this, "clientes", $data);
}

public function insertar()
{
    $data = $this->model->setUser();
    print_r($data);
}

public function verUsuarios()
{

    $data = $this->model->getClients();
    print_r($data);
}
}
```

**Models/clientesModel.php**

```
class clientesModel extends Mysql
{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function getClients()
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes";
    $viewClient = $this->select_all($sql);
    return $viewClient;
}
}
```

**Libraries/Core/Controllers.php**

```
    class Controllers
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->views = new Views();
        $this->loadModel();
    }

    public function loadModel()
    {
        //HomeModel.php
        $model = get_class($this)."Model";
        $routClass = "Models/".$model.".php";
        if(file_exists($routClass)){
            require_once($routClass);
            $this->model = new $model();
        }
    }
}
```

**Libreries/Core/autoload.php**

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    if(file_exists("Libraries/".'Core/'.$class.".php")){
        require_once("Libraries/".'Core/'.$class.".php");
    }
});
```

Comment: Antes del constructor de `Controllers` agrega `public $model;`

Comment: Eso ya lo he solucionado ahora me dice **: Error no detectado: llamada a una función miembro getClients () en nulo** si esta leyendo la función del modelo esta definida no?

Comment: Suponiendo que `get_class()` devuelva _Clientes_, intentas instanciar _clientesModel_ con la primera letra en minúscula.

Comment: Eliminé mi respuesta no era correcta porque clientesModel extiende a sql no a controllers

Comment: si se supone que ya esta instanciado despues del if no? En caso de que no, donde tengo que instanciar la clases en clientesModel.php en la parte del constructor?

Comment: Ojo: ¿Estás seguro de que `file_exists($routClass)` devuelve true?, esa parece una ruta relativa a `__DIR__` de modo que yo sugeriría verificar con un var_dump($routClass) al entrar al bloque. Seguro no se muestra

Comment: @quevedo me muestra esto **string(24) "Models/ClientesModel.php"** así que se supone que si me lo reconoce

Comment: Pero la objeción de @Triby es perfecta tratas de instanciar **clientesModel** usando **ClientesModel** y eso es *casesensitive* cambia la primera letra al nombre de la clase por mayúscula o al contrario cuando vayas a instanciar cambia a minúscula la primera letra.

Comment: te refieres a esto? **public function __construct()
    {
        $this->model =new clientesModel();
        parent::__construct();
    }**

Comment: eso lo he hecho en la clase clientesModel peor me sigue saliendo el mismo error

Comment: en la última línea que muestras: `$this->model = new $model();` el nombre en la variable  $model que usas para crear la instancia tiene C mayúscula

Comment: vale ya lo tengo convertido pero me da error **Error fatal: Error no detectado: la clase 'Conexión' no se encuentra en /opt/lampp/htdocs/mvc_gymArtCopia/Libraries/Core/Mysql.php:3** cuando esta extendido de mysql que se supone que lo requiere en el autoload.php

Comment: @quevedo he revisado mi proyecto y se supone de que autoload requiere los demas archivos así que no se donde falla

Comment: Verifica que la(s) ruta(s) que pasas al autoload lo estén apuntando. Si lo apuntan prueba a añadirlo a fuerza bruta usando include_once o require_once (esos sabores de los métodos no generan error al tratar de incluir algo que ya esté cargado) antes de instanciar la clase Conexion. Ah verifica la ortografía (suele ocurrir que por ser hispanohablantes se nos cuelen tildes)